# file a complaint to bureaus of a company's residence if you live in another country?

Tags: credit-card, online-payment, consumer-protection, refund

Can I submit a consumer complaint to Better Business Bureau, federal Trade Commissionn, or the Consumer Frauds and Protection Bureau if I've bought a faulty product froma  company based in Brooklyn, New York, but it has been shipped to me to Armenia and I'm not from US or a US citizen?
The shipping time took longer than the chargeback limit.

Comment: It doesn't harm to file the complaint first, they would refuse if they cannot take up your complain. Or try contacting their helpline or email them your query.

Comment: It's going to be a lengthy formal complaint. I'd like to know if I should even bother before taking the time to write it, if possible.

Comment: There is no harm in trying, other than the effort expended in typing in the complaint. Yes it is a complaint and it is going to be lengthy, I checked Better Business Bureau and it doesn't seem so. You don't want your money back ?

Comment: Why not email them and ask?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just asked if someone knew or not. I'm going to try if you don't know. But then I don't have an answer to mark in stackexchange.